# Retrieving already Initialized object value to c++ from Java using GetFieldId() JNI

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I do not have much experience of JNI and I am accessing the static Object of java to get in to c++.

```
My Java file:
Class ABC{

public static ABC abc = null;

//some functions
}
```

In my cpp file :

There is another class which Initializes the abc and I want that value to my cpp file.

for that what I am doing is :

in ABCJNI.h

```
 static jfieldID fid;
     jobject DatainJNI;
     static jobject DataRetrived;
     static ABCJNI abcjni;         //purpose is to take value of ABC abc to here in ABCJNI abcjni 

ABCJNI::initialize(){
    cls = StubJava::env->FindClass("metronome"); 
    constructorMetronomeData = StubJava::env->GetMethodID(cls, "<init>", "()V");
 
  
fid = StubJava::env->GetStaticFieldID( cls, "abc", "()LABC;");
  if (fid == 0)
    return 1;
  DataRetrived = StubJava::env->GetStaticObjectField( cls, fid);
  abcjni = ABCJNI(DataRetrived);
  return 0;

}

ABCJNI::ABCJNI(jobject retrivedvalue)
{
jobject FinalInstance=retrivedValue;
}
```

But I am getting compilation error on this line  abcDatainJNI = ABCJNI(DataRetrived);// it says undefined reference? as well I am not sure about the getting object value.

Comment: Which reference is undefined?

Comment: Field signatures do not have `()` in them. Use the output of `javah`: don't guess.

Comment: Your code sample raises more questions than it solves: What is the relation between "metronome" and "ABC"? Why are you getting the constructor if you're not going to use it? What is the point of putting "retrivedValue" in a local variable in the ABCJNI constructor? What does the ABCJNI class look like? Are you going to use the jobject inside ABCJNI directly? Otherwise you're missing a call to NewGlobalRef

Comment: Sorry its not  "metronome" its "ABCJNI". ,Constructor is just there for another purpose.That variable Jobject which is local will be used for other tasks.I can make it global as per requirement I did not get about NewGlobalRef

Comment: Sorry @MarquisofLorne I did not get you !

Comment: @talex Problem is here   abcjni = ABCJNI(DataRetrived);

Comment: Can you ad exact text of error?